# How can I map a file with mmap while allocating an empty page before it?

Tags: c, memory, mmap

so I need to map a file into memory, but at the same time allocate space infront of it to store some data along with it.

Basically I have this:

```c
int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) {
    // error
}

struct stat file_info;
if (fstat(fd, &file_info) == -1) {
    close(fd);
    // error
}

int length = file_info.st_size;
int* data_pointer = mmap((void*) 0, length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
close(fd);
```

and I'd like to have space infront of the memory, maybe like one page or something, where I can do this:

```c
*data_pointer = length; // store length in space before file

// print out contents of file

const char* p = data_pointer + PAGE_SIZE;
for (int i = 0; i < *data_pointer; i++) {
    printf("%c", p[i]);
} 

printf("\n");
```

so that I can do this later:

```c
munmap(data_pointer, *data_pointer + PAGE_SIZE);
```

for example. I've already tried allocating the amount of space I want with `malloc` and then telling `mmap` to map into that space with its `addr` argument, but I don't think that would work 100% of the time, since its more of a hint than an order, and I'm scared that on some platforms, the `mmap` implementation may ignore the `addr` argument completely.

Would you know of any better way to accomplish what I want without having to keep track of the size of every `mmap` call seperately (I'm sharing these pointers between dynamically loaded libraries, some of which do the `mmap`'ing, some of which do the `munmap`'ing, and it would be pretty inelegant to have to handle all of that is some kind of seperate list)?

It's late at night and I don't really think I'm making much sense here, but any help or insight would be greatly appreciated regardless. Thanks alot for your time in reading this!

Comment: Your request makes sense, but I don't think it's possible. You haven't really explained what you want to use the header data for, so I'd advise you to make a separate allocation instead, with a pointer to the mmap'd area.

Comment: That's probably exactly the solution I need to my problem actually. Thank you very much for your help :P

Comment: Side note: `printf("%s\n", *(data_pointer + PAGE_SIZE));` is not a safe way to print a memory-mapped file. It might have a null byte inside it, or worse, there probably won't be a null byte after the end of it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Turns out it is possible to do safely (see below).

Comment: Yup I'm aware that's not how you're supposed to print it, it was just to make my example more concise. Should I edit it?

Comment: @Inobulles I'd say yes, just because you know people copy-and-paste from here all the time without understanding it or reading the comments, and someday that will end up a security bug in some major company's app.

Comment: Gosh I sure hope big companies don't use my code as a reference! :D Anyhow I've edited my original post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. The missing piece you need is `MAP_FIXED`:

```
int* data_pointer = mmap((void*) 0, length + PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if(data_pointer == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(1);
}
if(mmap(data_pointer + PAGE_SIZE, length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0) == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(1);
}
```

You correctly pointed out that normally, the address is "more of a hint than an order", but passing `MAP_FIXED` makes it an order.

If you're worried about safety, [`man 2 mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says:

> The only safe use for `MAP_FIXED` is where the address range specified by `addr` and `length` was previously reserved using another mapping

And that's exactly this use.

Comment: Ooh ok. Are there any side-effects to MAP_FIXED that aren't mentionned in the man page such as performance issues? Thank you very much for your answer either way.

Comment: @Inobulles Not that I'm aware of. All of the caveats with it that I know of are mentioned there.